# Filter An Array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am trying to filter an array of object. I can filter and get result according to my condition but I would like to take action after filtering.

```
heroes = [

//match1  
{ 
    player1: { name: "Batman", score: 1},
    player2: { name: "Ironman", score: 3}
},
//match2 
{
    player1: { name: "Thor", score: 0},
    player2: { name: "Superman", score: 2}
},
//match3  
{
    player1: { name: "Superman", score: 4},
    player2: { name: "Batman", score: 1}
},
//match4  
{
    player1: { name: "Ironman", score: 3},
    player2: { name: "Thor", score: 5}
}

];
```

I am giving sample scenario. For example, I want to calculate total score of Batman in all matches. But as you can see, Batman is sometimes player1, sometimes player2.

This is why I am finding like this:

```
    //While Batman player1, find all matches and sum scores
      var player1matches = heroes.filter(match => match.player1.name.indexOf("Batman") > -1);
      var player1scores= player1matches .reduce(((acc, match) => acc + match.player1.score), 0);

    //While Batman player2, find all matches and sum scores
        var player2matches = heroes.filter(match => match.player2.name.indexOf("Batman") > -1);
        var player2scores= player1matches .reduce(((acc, match) => acc + match.player2.score), 0);

    //Total Batman scores 
        var batmanScore = player1scores+ player2scores
```

But this is not a good solution for sure because there are going to be lots of prop inside player1 object and I am going to use those data.

In short, I have lots of prop inside player1 and player2 objects. I want to sum/subs/count those data according to specific name.

Waiting your suggestions.

Comment: This array isn't valid. Also, are you sure you mean `while`,not `if`?

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? While this question is nicely formatted (and I'm thankful for that, coming from a new user), you have to post a working example that shows your problem, please.

Comment: For those of you who think this is an error, please understand that this is a perfectly valid syntax. EDIT: OP edited the question but the original was also correct

Comment: Yes, it has been working. Why it is not valid, I dont understand ? I am using chrome console

Comment: Your method of identifying which player is Batman is flawed: what if `Evil Batman` joined the game and deliberately lost every time? The real Batman's record would be ruined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly just reduce the array to get final score.

```
function calculateScoreForPlayer(heroes, playerName){
  return heroes.reduce( (result, currentHero) => {
    const p1 = currentHero.player1;
    const p2 = currentHero.player2;
    if(p1.name === playerName){
      result.score += p1.score;
    }
    if(p2.name === playerName){
      result.score += p2.score;
    }

    return result;
  } , { score : 0}).score;
}
```

EDIT: To answer the question from the comments

The original answer is just a short way do do

```
function calculateScoreForPlayer(heroes, playerName) {
    const result = heroes.reduce(
        (result, currentHero) => {
            const p1 = currentHero.player1;
            const p2 = currentHero.player2;
            if (p1.name === playerName) {
                result.score += p1.score;
            }
            if (p2.name === playerName) {
                result.score += p2.score;
            }

            return result;
        }, { score: 0 });

    return result.score;
}
```

Instead of storing the result in a temporary variable `result`, I was just returning the actual object.

Assuming the output score is 3, if you don't do that `.score` part - you will get an object `{ score: 3 }`
If you do do `.score` you will get `3` as output.

Hope that helps

Comment: Could you explain the functionality of the **.score** at the end of your code. I deleted it and still it works. Why do we need this ?

Comment: @CanerSezgin updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit confusing, to be honest, but going off of what you said, here's a solution. Also, I believe your array is declared incorrectly, if you want an array of matches, try this:

```
matches = [
    { 
        player1: { name: "Batman", score: 1},
        player2: { name: "Ironman", score: 3}
    },
    {
        player1: { name: "Thor", score: 0},
        player2: { name: "Superman", score: 2}
    },
    {
        player1: { name: "Superman", score: 4},
        player2: { name: "Batman", score: 1}
    },
    {
        player1: { name: "Ironman", score: 3},
        player2: { name: "Thor", score: 5}
    }

];
```

Then, you could just go through the matches, and if either of the players are `batman`, create a sum and add his points to it.

```
var batmanTotalPoints = 0;

heroes.forEach(function(match) {
    if(match.player1.name === 'Batman') batmanTotalPoints += match.player1.score;
    else if (match.player2.name === 'Batman') batmanTotalPoints += match.player2.score;
})
```

But all of the other answers here would work great as well! Using `reduce` would also be a great option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solutions works for me. 
I have another question about validation of array because it was little bit controversial as you see in the comments under my post :) 
I tried  exactly like you wrote at the beginning but I received an **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"** error. This is why I changed it to the version that I posted. Again, I tried this in chrome console and again I am receiving same error. 'hat's wrong ?

Comment: @CanerSezgin I actually corrected my code! I had a misunderstanding and wasn't familiar with how you were writing your array. But, I corrected it. Try that out. The problem was an array doesn't have keys and values like an object. Try it out and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

For each match, we examine each player. For each player, we do one of two things:

1. If the player's name matches the name required, we take the score
2. If the player's name doesn't match, we take 0

We then get the sum of the score for each match. We then get the sum of all the matches. This gives us the total score for that name.

```js
heroes = [
  match1 = { 
      player1: { name: "Batman", score: 1},
      player2: { name: "Ironman", score: 3}
  },
  match2 = {
      player1: { name: "Thor", score: 0},
      player2: { name: "Superman", score: 2}
  },
  match3 = {
      player1: { name: "Superman", score: 4},
      player2: { name: "Batman", score: 1}
  },
  match4 = {
      player1: { name: "Ironman", score: 3},
      player2: { name: "Thor", score: 5}
  }
];

const getNameScore = (input, name) => input
  .map(match => Object.keys(match)
    .map(key => match[key].name === name ?
      match[key].score : 0 
    ).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0)
  ).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0)
  
console.dir(getNameScore(heroes, "Ironman"))
console.dir(getNameScore(heroes, "Batman"))
console.dir(getNameScore(heroes, "Thor"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getScore(name) {
  return heroes.map(x => { //Map each match to either a score or NULL
    if (x.player1.name === name) return x.player1.score;
    if (x.player2.name === name) return x.player2.score;
    return null;
  })
  .filter(x => null !== x) //Remove NULL
  .reduce((acc, current) => acc + current); //Sum
}

console.log(getScore('Superman')); // => 6
console.log(getScore('Batman')); // => 2
console.log(getScore('Thor')); // => 5
```

In this example we map each match to either a score (an integer) or **NULL**. After that, we remove any NULL values by filtering them, and then reduce them to a single integer by adding them together. This gives us one final integer - the total score.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a naive solution providing you will refactor the proposed array since it's not valid. 
Here is a working example :

```js
// it's actually matchs and not heroes
// at least for me :)
matchs = [
  // match 1
  [{
      name: "Batman",
      score: 1
    }, // player 1
    {
      name: "Ironman",
      score: 3
    }
  ], // player 2

  // match 2
  [{
      name: "Thor",
      score: 0
    }, // player 1
    {
      name: "Superman",
      score: 2
    }
  ], // player 2

  // match 3
  [{
      name: "Superman",
      score: 4
    }, // player 1
    {
      name: "Batman",
      score: 1
    }
  ], // player 2

  // match 4
  [{
      name: "Ironman",
      score: 3
    }, // player 1
    {
      name: "Thor",
      score: 5
    }
  ], // player 2

]

function heroScore(name) {

  let score = 0;

  // loop through matchs
  matchs.forEach(match => {
    if (match[0].name === name ||
      match[1].name === name) {
      score += match[0].name === name ? match[0].score : match[1].score;
    }
  });

  return score;
}

console.log("Batman : " + heroScore("Batman"));
console.log("Thor : " + heroScore("Thor"));
console.log("Superman : " + heroScore("Superman"));
console.log("Ironman : " + heroScore("Ironman"));
```

This solution is not performance efficient, as it parses every element in the ``matchs` array which may be ressource consuming if the array is too long;

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options, but if you will need the other properties, you might want to mend your data structure:

```js
let matches = getData();


//create a new player and match key for each player and only an array of players
let flattened = []
matches.forEach((match,match_num)=>{
  for(let player in match){
    let new_player = Object.assign({},match[player]);
    new_player.player = player;
    new_player.match  = match_num+1;
    flattened.push(new_player)
  }
});
console.log('flattened:\n',flattened);


// Batman
const batman = flattened.filter(player=>player.name.toLowerCase()=='batman')
console.log('batman:\n',batman);

// Sums
const scores = flattened.reduce((acc,player)=>{
  if (typeof acc[player.name] == 'undefined')
    acc[player.name]=0;
  acc[player.name] += +player.score;
  return acc;
},{});
console.log('scores:\n', scores);



function getData() {
  return [

    //match1  
    {
      player1: {
        name: "Batman",
        score: 1
      },
      player2: {
        name: "Ironman",
        score: 3
      }
    },
    //match2 
    {
      player1: {
        name: "Thor",
        score: 0
      },
      player2: {
        name: "Superman",
        score: 2
      }
    },
    //match3  
    {
      player1: {
        name: "Superman",
        score: 4
      },
      player2: {
        name: "Batman",
        score: 1
      }
    },
    //match4  
    {
      player1: {
        name: "Ironman",
        score: 3
      },
      player2: {
        name: "Thor",
        score: 5
      }
    }

  ];
}
```